# Contact Form - UX after Submit

Tags: forms

When submitting a form in a contact page, what do you prefer?

For me it's better to keep the data in the fields, disable the fields, disable the submit button and give a feedback message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable** the form fields and button after form submit.

*Case 1:* On form submit **SUCCESS**

- Hide/Remove the form fields. (If success there is no need to retain the form data)
- Show the success message.

*Case 2:* On form submit **FAILURE**

- Enable the form fields and button (User data retains even after the unsuccessful submit)
- Show the failure message like toast notification (Try again later or something).